# ie7 z-index bug... having trouble fixing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

I have 2 columns (several rows) of divs like this:

```
<div class="odd">
    <div class="desc"></div>
</div>
<div class="even">
    <div class="desc"></div>
</div>
```

the `odd` and `even` classes are positioned relatively with z-index of 1 and the `desc` classes are positioned absolutely with a z-index of 5. Its set so that the `desc` inside the `odd` overlaps the `even` to the right, and the `desc` inside the `even` overlaps the `odd` to the left.

This works fine except in `ie7`. the `desc` from the `odd` is showing as under the `even`. I tried several things and the only solution I came up with just inverted my problem I set `odd` to a z-index of 2 and `even` to a z-index of 1 but then the desc from the even hides under the odd.

I hope this makes sense. I am basically showing products, when you hover over the image a description pops up to the side (over the product next to it, left or right for even or odd). Its working fine except for ie8.

Is there a fix?

### update

here is the css:

```
.even, .odd
{
    padding:5px;
    width:332px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.desc
{
    height:300px;
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    z-index:5;
    width:300px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.even:hover .desc, .odd:hover .desc
{
    visibility:visible; 
}

.even:hover .desc:hover, .odd:hover .desc:hover
{
    visibility:hidden;  
}

.even .desc
{
    right:100%;
}
.odd .desc
{
    left:100%;  
}
```

Comment: Can you post your css? It makes sense, but it's not easy to see it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The parent z-index always takes precedence over its child's index. This is the official W3C definition of the behaviour. So it really doesn't matter if your desc1 and desc2 have 10 and resp. 400 as z-index value as long as your odd class have 1 and even has 2, even always will be on top.